# Ubuntu 18.04 screen saver / lock - how to turn it off?

Tags: gnome, 18.04

In Ubuntu 18.04 anytime I walk away from the computer this screen appears after 5 minutes, no matter what settings I put in **Privacy > Screen Lock**:

[image: Ubuntu 18 screen saver]

First of all I want to ask you guys: what is this screen technically called? I tried to search for "screen lock" or "screen saver" in Ubuntu 18.04 but I got results about something else. I think technically speaking this is NOT screen lock since you are not required to use your password.

However, in Ubuntu 16 the screen would just go black and moving the mouse would be enough to use the computer again.

What's super annoying in Ubuntu 18.04 is that here you have to drag that arrow (as you can see on the screenshot) up in order to be able to use the computer again... Where do I disable that?

Comment: Some call it the Watch screen I think. Others the swipe screen as it mimics cell phones. Lots of people hate it no matter what it is called.